# Show Timing but assign the result directly

Tags: real-time

The code `a=2+2//Timing`
assigns the variable `a` to `{time,4}` . How can I show the evaluation time, but still assign `a` with the result of `2+2` directly (in one line)?

---

I have tried defining a custom Timing function (**working now**)

```
showTiming[in_] :=  Block[{res}, res = Timing[in]; Print[res[[1]], " s"]; res[[2]] ]
SetAttributes[showTiming, HoldAll] (* <- IMPORTANT!*)

a=2+2//showTiming
```

Comment: Obviously 2+2 is going to show zero... 2+2 is extremely fast to calculate. If you want to test it more, try timing something difficult like factoring big numbers e.g `a = FactorInteger[Times @@ RandomPrime[2^70, 2]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing missing from your definition of `showTiming` was a `HoldAll` or `HoldFirst` attribute.  Without that attribute the argument `in` is evaluated before being handed off to `showTiming`.

---

Since V12.2 there is a function, `EchoTiming`, that effectively does the same thing as your function, but using `Echo` instead of `Print` to display the time.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at my attempt and explaining the ```HoldAll``` function.

Answer (score 1):

In one line this looks a bit ugly:

```
(a = Last@#; Print@*First@#) &@Timing[2 + 2]
(* 0. and a is set to 4 *)
```

With a harder workload:

```
(a = Last@#; Print@*First@#) &@Timing[
  FactorInteger[Times @@ RandomPrime[2^70, 2]]
]
(* 0.34375, and a is set to the factorization *)
```

Maybe you could have this as a function like:

```
TimedExpr[expr_] := (Last@#; Print@*First@#;) &@Timing[expr]
SetAttributes[TimedExpr, HoldAll]

(* example *)
TimedExpr[
 b = FactorInteger[Times @@ RandomPrime[2^70, 2]]
]
```

Comment: (for other users): this does not show the result of the evaluation. But removing the semicolon in the parenthesis achieves that, ```(Print@*First@#; Last@#) &```.

Comment: Thank you @flinty for taking the time to do this function. I would have liked to accept both answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 2+2; // Timing // First
```

You can leave out the `// First` for simplicity.